# Cake PHP Use Conditions and Order By in Paginate

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to use Conditions and Order By in cake PHP paginate function of the Paginator helper

This is my code which I'm using

```
$this->set('equipment', $this->Paginator->paginate('Equipment',array('conditions' => array('Equipment.equipment_type_id' => 19), 'order' => array('Equipment.problem_count', 'Equipment.barcode DESC'))));
```

But it gives me this error

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conditions' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Equipment`.`id`, `Equipment`.`equipment_type_id`, `Equipment`.`barcode`, `Equipment`.`problem_count`, `Equipment`.`description`, `Equipment`.`created`, `Equipment`.`modified`, `EquipmentType`.`id`, `EquipmentType`.`name`, `EquipmentType`.`created`, `EquipmentType`.`modified` FROM `unlibike`.`equipment` AS `Equipment` LEFT JOIN `unlibike`.`equipment_types` AS `EquipmentType` ON (`Equipment`.`equipment_type_id` = `EquipmentType`.`id`) WHERE conditions = (19) AND `order` IN ('Equipment.problem_count', 'Equipment.barcode DESC') LIMIT 20

By looking at the SQL query generated it looks like Cake PHP is interpreting 'conditions' and 'Order' as a column.

Can Anyone Help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params in order of Paginator::paginate

```
* @param Model|string $object Model to paginate (e.g: model instance, or 'Model', or 'Model.InnerModel')
* @param string|array $scope Additional find conditions to use while paginating
* @param array $whitelist List of allowed fields for ordering. This allows you to prevent ordering
 *   on non-indexed, or undesirable columns. See PaginatorComponent::validateSort() for additional details
 *   on how the whitelisting and sort field validation works.
```

http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-PaginatorComponent.html#_paginate

Example :

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'order'=>array('yourfields');
);

$this->Pagniator->paginate('Equipment', $conditionsArray ) ;
```

Comment: first model, 2nd conditions , 3rd sort & options

Comment: I changed my code to this $this->set('equipment', $this->Paginator->paginate('Equipment',array(
   
    'Equipment.equipment_type_id' => 19
   
   ),
  array(
   
    'Equipment.problem_count', 
    'Equipment.barcode DESC'
    
   )
  ));

It give the list of the enteries in the table but doesn't sort them according to the fields i mentioned

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the 3rd parameter?

Comment: $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'order'=>array('yourfields');
);